# Unable to Establish VNC Display on Ubuntu 20.04 Jetson Nano without HDMI Connection. Shows 'DISPLAY' environment variable not set... when i SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, vnc

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

1. Manually setting the DISPLAY environment variable as both `DISPLAY=:1` and `DISPLAY="my ip:1"`.
2. Verifying the display variable using `echo $DISPLAY`, which shows the expected value.
3. Rebooting the system after setting the DISPLAY environment variable, but the issue persists.

I suspect that there might be some additional configuration or settings required to ensure the VNC display works properly without an HDMI connection.

How can I configure the system to enable VNC display without the need for an HDMI connection?

Answer (score 1):

yeah you should configure vnc on your jetson first ,
you can use this link https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/learn/tutorials/vnc-setup